# If we have f=2x^2+log(x), if big O(f)=x^2, then what does Omega(f)=?

Tags: algorithm

is it log(x) since Omega is the best case possible? then if f=x+1, is Omega(f)= 1 then?

Comment: so for f=100n+logn and g=n+log(n)^2, it would be f=O(g) since f<cg and not f=omega(g) right?

Answer (score 4):

No, `Omega` is for asymptotic lower bounds in much the same way that `O` is for asymptotic upper bounds. So, `f = Omega(g)` if for some constant `C` it is eventually true that `f >= C * g`. That is, there is a constant `C` and a constant `N` such that `n >= N` implies `f(n) >= C * g(n)`. It's the same as `O` just with the direction of the inequality reversed.

Answer (score 3):

Nor O nor Omega work that way. You can also not say O(f) = x^2

Instead, one says: f = O(g) which means that there are constants k and C, such that: f < k*g + C

Therefore the following statements are true for your f:

- f = O(x^2)
- f = O(x^2 + log(x))
- f = O(x^3)
- f = O(x^145321)

Omega works the same way, but with the inequality reversed:
f = Omega(g) which means that there are constants k and C, such that: f > k*g + C

Therefore the following statements are true for your f:

- f = Omega(log(x))
- f = Omega(x^2 + log(x))
- f = Omega(1)
- f = Omega(x)

Hope this helps. For more information, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations)

Answer (score 2):

A lot of people think that *O* means "worst case" and *Omega* means "best case", but that is *not* correct. The statement *f(x) = O(g(x))* loosely means "*f(x)* does not grow faster than *c g(x)* (for some constant *c*), while *f(x) = Omega(g(x))* loosely means "*f(x)* does not grow slower than *c g(x)*". Note that in *both* of these statements, it is the "biggest" term (in this case, *2x^2*), that you should look at, so *f(x)* is both *O(x^2)* and *Omega(x^2)* (and it is also *O(x^3)*, *O(2^x)*, *Omega(x)*, *Omega(1)* and so on). The most important thing to note, though, is that *both O and Omega are statements about the function f(x)*. They do *not* care about what the function describes, and have no notion about best or worst cases. Rather, it is *customary* to use *O* to describe a function when the function represents a worst case, and to use *Omega* when the function represents a best case. The reason for this is that if we have an *O* bound for a function that represents the worst case for an algorithm, then that same *O* bound applies to the algorithm's run time in *all* cases (since it never can use more time than in the worst case), and similarly, an *Omega* bound for a best case applies to the algorithm's run time in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more very important notation from practical point of view. Big Theta notation. The idea is this same as with big O and big Omega, but the function is bounded both from above and below.